# datatable on single cell multiples values

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have `DataTable` which I add `Columns` and `Rows` from database. Problem is I have one cell which has multiples record like `province` can be multiples in database.  So I need to create multiple records in one cell of province. My code is

```
  foreach (var item in attributes)
    {
        table.Columns.Add(item.name);
        //column add


    }

    foreach (var item in forms)
    {
        string FormId = Convert.ToString(item);
        var row = table.NewRow();
        row["Form Id"] = FormId;
        foreach (var itemdata in attributes)
        {

            var value = attributesData.FirstOrDefault(t => t.attributeName == itemdata.name && t.strFormId == FormId);
            if (value != null && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value.strFormId) == false )
            {
                row[itemdata.name] = value.strValue;

                //row add
            }
         }

        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }

        gvView.DataSource = table;
```

I bind this with my GridView. How to break one cell with mutliples records please help.

Comment: What is 'attribute' here?

Comment: attribute is list of columns where every data is comes like province district and village now i have to break province in one cell multiples

Comment: You want the data as comma separated?

Comment: How do you want to represent your data in that cell `,` separated or multiple records with same data for other cells and different for this one cell ?

Comment: no, i wants on each rows where province comes make province cell with multiple values province cell can have multiple values so i need to display on gridview data view .

Comment: multiple record with same data will be good

Comment: @rajaatif - Better show some sample input\ output you're expecting.